# 40/60 split screen with container

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am wondering what is the best way to achieve two background divs (blue and gray) with a container over the top of them (red):

http://s22.postimg.org/44kcq1cqp/screenshot_413.png

I would create two divs for the background colours and 100vh but how would I overlay a container on top so I can make the login area? I'm trying to achieve something like this design:

http://s22.postimg.org/584h1zxdt/screenshot_414.png

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is how I would do that :)

https://fiddle.jshell.net/okjn0oca/

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.content{
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

.left{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 40vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: blue;
}

.right {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 60vw;
  background-color: green
}

.menu {
  width: calc(100% - 30px);
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 15px auto;
}

.logo {
  width: 60px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 15px;
}

.text{
  position: absolute;
  width: 30vw;
  height: 100px;
  left: 5vw;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="left">
    <div class="logo">
      
    </div>
    <div class="text">
      
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <div class="menu">
      
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Vashnak, could you include the code in your answer?

Comment: @DouwedeHaan Done !

Answer (score 0):

You could use a 1px background image on the body:

```
background: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAFeCAYAAABEunUfAAAAG0lEQVR42mMUYPj/n3GUGCVGiVFilBglhgMBAK5H0KGRPNKKAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC) no-repeat;
background-size: 40% 100%;
```

[Here's a Codepen with the example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rwLpaQ)

With the background size you force the pixel to cover 40% of the width and 100% of the height.

The 1px background is generated with [png-pixel.com](http://png-pixel.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you have actually tried anything, but here's something you can try.

Assuming you only want to have split colors for the background, you don't have to use two divs for that. You can do that with gradient (don't forget vendor prefixes). Then it's just a matter of positioning the "overlay" div as you want.

```css
.bg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0,56,199,1) 0%, rgba(0,56,199,1) 40%, rgba(74,74,74,1) 40%, rgba(74,74,74,1) 100%);
}

.overlay {
  width: 60%;
  height: 25%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
  left: 10%;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg">
  <div class="overlay"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a single container.

```
 <style>
  .main
  {
      background:white;
  }

  .login
  {
       background:blue;
  }
</style>


  <div class="main">
        <div class="col-md-5 no-margin">
           leave it blank
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-7 no-margin login">
           put your page contents here
        </div>
  </div>
```